# Android | ListView Using Layoutinflater

Tags: android, xml, listadapter

Im Writing An Application that reads XML file and Displays it as a ListView
cause each row has its own Image and Text i am using LayoutInflater, i can display the Texts but cant display Images! this is the code i use for ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdaptertwo extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> values;
    private final ArrayList<String> values2;

    public ImageAdaptertwo(Context context, ArrayList<String> values,ArrayList<String> values2) {
        super(context, R.layout.trimester1_listview, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.values2 = values2;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String s = values.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trimester1_main, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label2);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon2);
        textView.setText(values2.get(position));

        // Change icon based on name
        //String s = values.get(position);

        System.out.println(s);

        if (s.equals(" havingsuccessful-pregnancyS.png")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n1);
        } else if (s.equals("urfoodguideduringpregnancyS.png")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n2);
        } else if (s.equals("lovingurpregnantbodyS.png")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n3);
        } else if (s.equals("gettinggoodbreastafterS.png")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n4);
        } else if (s.equals("FoodGuidePyramidS.png")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n5);
        } else if (s.equals("pregnancyS.png")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n6);
        } else if (s.equals("nutritionfoS.png")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n7);
        } else if (s.equals("Your-Growing-ChildS.png")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n8);
        } else if (s.equals("Fatigue-in-first-trimesterS.png")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n9);
        } else if (s.equals("T1S.png")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n10);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

values and values2 are the ArrayList which are Coming from XML Parser! Actually no they are ok because i print the content of them and see them in LogCat!
in my Activit i use this for Adapting ImageAdapter

```
setListAdapter(new ImageAdaptertwo(this, imagelink,texts));
```

The result is a listview with texts but no Images!
can anybody tell me how i can fix this and display XML contents on ListView?

Solved the problem by changing if Statements to Switch Case . now for each row i have specific number

Comment: Put a default else case in your if else statements and set some image to see if its an image problem or an if else problem

Comment: i think there may be problem in your trimester1_main layout..make sure the imageview is visible in the layout

Comment: if you have tried suggestion given by Slartibartfast then there must be some layout problem....ok then just try putting a default image in your layout

Comment: @manindersingh setting a default value just worked! now all the images are the same but text diffrent...

       if (s.equals(" havingsuccessful-pregnancyS.png")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n1);}
   else{
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n10);
   }

now what should i do?

Comment: @Slartibartfast Default image worked! there is problem in if else ... but how to fix it?

Comment: can you show the output of System.out.println(s);

Comment: try with equalsIgnoreCase ? Did you try to print String in getView method ?

Comment: @manindersingh Solved the problem by changing if Statements to Switch Case . now for each row i have specific number

now do u have any idea for showing this when i get online Image?! in this case all the content are on the drawable but what if they are coming online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically a problem in your if - else then. String comparisons are not happening as you expect. Make sure you check any code involving equals,equalsignorecase twice in JAVA. String comparisons are unnecessarily complicated. Also instead of if-else you can use switch and make your life just a little bit easier.
To get images from online you have to get the images on a background thread and then display on the main thread. 
See this for help : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Similar question: [unable to display url image (bitmap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971032/unable-to-display-url-image-bitmap/12971134#12971134)

Comment: @Slartibarfast
 Do u have any comment if i want to show another group of pictures what should i do?! except creating another class called ImageAdapter3!
i mean i have another XML file which is going to display like this! can i have one Adapter for both? images in XML files are diffrent...

Comment: Well you d want to have two just to separate both sets of ui.  If you want one for both you could add an activity constructor parameter that identifies where you are calling it from and then use it to inflate appropriate xmls. Or maybe an interface that both your adapter classes could implement.  Many ways.  It really depends on how you look at the architecture of your app

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by changing if Statements to Switch Case . now for each row i have specific image